# Bound on and integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

If $\alpha \in \Bbb R$, how can I show $$\int_{-M}^M \frac{1}{\sqrt{|x-\alpha|}} \, dx \le 4 \sqrt{M}$$

For $M>0$, Rewriting the integral gives $$\int_{-M+\alpha}^{M + \alpha} \frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|}} \, dx$$

What to do if, $|\alpha|>M$?

Comment: Actually $$\int_{-M}^M \frac{1}{\sqrt{|x - \alpha|}}\, dx = \int_{-M-\alpha}^{M - \alpha} \frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|}}\, dx$$

Comment: Does that mean the answer is incorrect?

Comment: Technically yes, but it's a very small technicality. Instead you'll have $$\int_{-M}^M \frac{1}{\sqrt{|x - \alpha|}}\, dx = 2\sqrt{M - \alpha} - 2\sqrt{-M - \alpha}$$ if $\alpha < -M$ and $$\int_{-M}^M \frac{1}{\sqrt{|x - \alpha|}}\, dx = 2\sqrt{M + \alpha} - 2\sqrt{-M + \alpha}$$ if $\alpha > M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\alpha > M$ you have by direct computation that $$\int_{-M + \alpha}^{M + \alpha} \frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|}} \, dx = 2 \sqrt{M + \alpha} - 2 \sqrt{-M + \alpha}.$$
The function $\phi(\alpha) = 2 \sqrt{M + \alpha} - 2 \sqrt{-M + \alpha}$ is decreasing for $\alpha \ge M$ (its first derivative is negative) so that $\alpha \ge M$ implies $\phi(\alpha) \le \phi(M) = (2 \sqrt 2) \sqrt{M} < 4\sqrt M$. If $\alpha < - M$ the proof is nearly identical.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Here's a more explicit derivation of the result Umberto refers to.

Assume $M>0$ and $\left|\alpha\right|>M$.

Substituting $y=x-\alpha$, splitting up the interval of integration, and substituting $z=-y$ in the first integral, we find:

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-M}^{M}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{\left|x-\alpha\right|}}
&=\int_{-M-\alpha}^{M-\alpha}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\sqrt{\left|y\right|}}\\
&=\int_{-M-\alpha}^{0}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\sqrt{\left|y\right|}}+\int_{0}^{M-\alpha}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\sqrt{\left|y\right|}}\\
&=\int_{M+\alpha}^{0}\frac{-\mathrm{d}z}{\sqrt{\left|-z\right|}}+\int_{0}^{M-\alpha}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\sqrt{\left|y\right|}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{M+\alpha}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\sqrt{\left|z\right|}}+\int_{0}^{M-\alpha}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\sqrt{\left|y\right|}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{M+\alpha}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\sqrt{\left|y\right|}}+\int_{0}^{M-\alpha}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\sqrt{\left|y\right|}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{M+\left|\alpha\right|}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\sqrt{y}}-\int_{0}^{\left|\alpha\right|-M}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\sqrt{y}}.\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: If $|\alpha| > M$ then $1/\sqrt{|y|}$ is continuous on $[-M-\alpha,M - \alpha]$.